# How to convert UTC timestamp to Australian time

Tags: r, timestamp

I have a large amount of data with timestamps in the following format: 2013-11-14T23:52:29Z.

My research indicates that the timezone is UTC (denoted by a "Z" suffix).

I need to convert it to +1100 UTC (which is Australia/Sydney time), also known as "EDT" (or Eastern Daylight Time).

I have tried the following:

```
test_timestamp <- "2013-11-14T23:52:29Z"
as.POSIXct(test_timestamp,"Australia/Sydney")
```

This produces the output `"2013-11-14 EST"`

This does not pass a sanity test as it should roll the date over into the next calendar day (i.e. 2013-11-15 EST).

I have wasted many hours on this seemingly trivial task, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, with a full `format` specified (see `?strptime`):

```
format(
  as.POSIXct(test_timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",tz="UTC"),
  tz="Australia/Sydney"
)
#[1] "2013-11-15 10:52:29"
```

Compare your attempt (essentially):

```
format(as.POSIXct(test_timestamp,tz="Australia/Sydney"),tz="Australia/Sydney")
#[1] "2013-11-14"
```

Also, this will work to non-destructively edit the data, only altering the output:

```
result <- as.POSIXct(test_timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",tz="UTC")
result
#[1] "2013-11-14 23:52:29 UTC"
#dput(result)
#structure(1384473149, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

attr(result,"tzone") <- "Australia/Sydney"
#dput(result)
#structure(1384473149, class = c("POSIXct","POSIXt"), tzone = "Australia/Sydney")
result
#[1] "2013-11-15 10:52:29 EST"
```

Comment: Question: If the original time was 23:52:29 UTC on 11-14, then how is 00:52:29 on 11-15, 11 hours later?

Comment: @jlhoward - good point, I missed the UTC in the original `as.POSIXct(...)` call - it's fixed now.

Comment: Ahh, I just came back to ask about this - thanks for the tip.